# Вернуть Observable 1 раз

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular4, rxjs, observer

Есть такой код. Работает вроде нормально, но заметил что при каждой следующей подписке возвращает 2, 3, 4 і тд раз результат; Ну тоесть на странице с подпиской когда я с нее ухожу и возврашаюсь то срабатывает `subscribe` уже 2 раза, потом 3 и тд. на `ngOnDestroy` отписываюсь, без отписки вообще память утекала сразу и вкладка зависала.

PS: знаю что при подписке можно написать `.first()`, но думаю это не лучший вариант.

Суть в том, чтоб при первой подписке получить значение и далее его всем возвращать.

[image: код]

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать оператор `take` из `rxjs`

```
this.yourService.yourSubject
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(...)
```

take(1) - берет первое значение и останавливает наблюдение.
Не забудьте добавить импорт.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html